# Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '3ML80909540'

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a legacy database and corresponding domain classes are like

```
class Assets{
    String id
    AssetsFinancial assetsFinancial = new AssetsFinancial()
    static constraints = {
        assetsFinancial(nullable: true)
    }
    static mapping = {
        version false
        id generator: "assigned", column: '`id`'
        assetsFinancial column: '`id`', insertable: false, updateable: false
    }
}
```

and

```
class AssetsFinancial{
    Integer appraisal
    Boolean doubleTerVar
    static mapping = {
        version false
        id generator: "assigned"
    }
    static constraints = {
        appraisal nullable: true
        doubleTerVar nullable: true
    }
}
```

when I am updating a property of AssetsFinancial instance like `assetsFinancialInstance.appraisal=2222` and the hibernate tries to 'commit' it's changes it gives me

```
| Error 2014-12-25 18:56:34,459 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '3ML80909540'
| Error 2014-12-25 18:56:34,726 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MysqlDataTruncation occurred when processing request: [POST] /someController/someAction/1295448
Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '3ML80909540'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: could not execute statement
    Line | Method
->>   53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     49 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     67 | doFilter  in com.studentsonly.grails.plugins.uiperformance.CacheFilter
|    270 | doFilter  in com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '3ML80909540'
->> 3560 | checkErrorPacket in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
```

I spent many hours to find the cause but not able to figure out the cause, any clue will be helpful for me.If any more information required the please ask.

**Update: Hibernate logs**

```
2014-12-26 14:51:35,099 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - update assets_financial set appraisal=?,  double_ter_var=? where id=?
2014-12-26 14:51:35,100 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1003]
2014-12-26 14:51:35,100 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [BOOLEAN] - [false]
2014-12-26 14:51:35,101 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [1298944]
```

Comment: Try this http://www.trk7.com/blog/getting-rid-of-mysql-warning-truncated-incorrect-double-value/

Comment: Try configuring SQL logging with parameters too. I don't think it's the appraisal column that fails.

Comment: I have already configured SQL logging with parameters but it does not tell me exact in which column is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And Finally I found the culprit

As we can see from SQL logging
`2014-12-26 14:51:35,101 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [1298944]` here data type is BIGINT but it should be VARCHAR then I add `String id` in my `AssetsFinancial`

```
class AssetsFinancial{
String id
//rest of code
}
```

and now all is well :)